# How to solve the Winforms Control.Invoke Error?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to solve the "**Control.Invoke must be used to interact with controls created on a separated thread**" Error Exception

```
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, portNo)); 
serverSocket.Listen(5); 
Socket client = serverSocket.Accept(); 
MessageBox.Show("Client Connected"); 

//Sent to Client 
NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client); 
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns); 
writer.AutoFlush = true; 
writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); 

//Receive from Client NetworkStream 
Stream nets = new NetworkStream(client); 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nets); 
string clientIPAddress = reader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Edit the snippet to show the code that fails.

Comment: Are you positively sure that it is this bit of code that causes the exception? The only place where you actually (implicitly) create UI controls is through the call to `MessageBox.Show`, but I heretofore thought that this method doesn't have to be run on the UI ("main") thread. Are you actually using multi-threading in your program?

Answer (score 0):

By doing what it says? It sounds like you're in some kind of callback, but (due to thread affinity) you can *only* talk to controls on their associated thread. So:

```
string newAnswer = LongComplexCode(); // on worker thread here
someControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    /* your work here, e.g. */
    someControl.Text = newAnswer; // on UI thread here
});
```

Comment: //My Coding is,
Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback,portNo));
serverSocket.Listen(5);
Socket client = serverSocket.Accept();
MessageBox.Show("Client Connected");
//Sent to Client
NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
writer.AutoFlush = true;
writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
//Receive from Client
NetworkStream nets = new NetworkStream(client);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nets);
string clientIPAddress=reader.ReadLine();